# Analytically isomorphic domain to $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I would like the ask why the following argument is true?

"Any proper domain of complex numbers $\mathbb C$ cannot be analytically isomorphic to $\mathbb C$."

I cannot deduce it by using [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem).

Comment: Can you define proper domain?

Comment: $D \subset \mathbb C$ with $D \neq \mathbb C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, suppose that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected. By the Riemann mapping theorem, $\Omega$ is conformally equivalent to the unit disk $D_1(0).$ If $\Omega$ were conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{C},$ then it would be conformally equivalent to $D_1(0).$ This cannot happen, as Liouville's theorem says that such a function must be constant, and constant functions are not conformal. If $\Omega$ is not simply connected, then it can't even be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ (since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected).